# Service worker is being cached by workbox

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have the following workbox configuration

```
config.plugins.push(
    new GenerateSW({
      swDest: 'service-worker.js',
      clientsClaim: true,
      // Only cache PWA version. Excludes pre-rendered AMP pages
      exclude: [/^(?!shell).*index\.html$/],
      // PWA routing ie single page app
      navigateFallback: '/shell/index.html',
      navigateFallbackBlacklist: [
        /*\.js.*/
      ],
    }),
  )
```

My express server does not cache the service worker

```
import serve from 'serve-static'

function setHeaders(res: Response, file: string) {
  let cache =
    basename(file) === 'service-worker.js'
      ? 'private,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,proxy-revalidate'
      : 'public,max-age=31536000,immutable'
  return res.setHeader('Cache-Control', cache) // don't cache service worker file
}
app.use(serve(BUILD_LOCATION, { setHeaders }))
```

1. First access of the page works as expected. The `service-worker.js` is returned to be the latest version and precaches all assets and the `shell.html`.
2. On refresh, as expected, the `shell.html` is served instead of going to the server and the assets are served from the service worker.
3. Let's say I rebuild the assets and update `service-worker.js`.
4. I expect the new `service-worker.js` to be loaded from the server and all new assets to be precached.

Instead I see the following the empty response

[image]
[image]
[image]

And I get the following error in the console `The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`

So it looks like the service worker is serving `shell/index.html` instead of going to the server for `service-worker.js`. To verify this I accessed `view-source:https://localhost/service-worker.js` shown below. How can I stop the service worker from caching itself. I thought that's what I was doing with `navigateFallbackBlacklist`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Going to `view-source:https://localhost/service-worker.js` in a browser will trigger a navigation request for `https://localhost/service-worker.js`, and then show you the resulting text content of the HTTP response for that navigation request.

That's not how updates to the service worker would normally be fetched—the normal update flow will make a non-navigation request to your server.

If you want an accurate view of the contents of your `service-worker.js` response, I'd recommend clicking on that request in the Network panel and then going to the "Response" panel of the viewer, like:

[image: Network panel's Response view]

Alternatively, you can visit `https://localhost/service-worker.js` in an Incognito window, and even though that will result in a navigation request, the Incognito window shouldn't have an associated service worker, so that navigation request won't get intercepted.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had checked the response panel but I didn't include above because it is empty. I have now included a screenshot above. As you can see it says `0B` were transferred.

Comment: Source code here https://github.com/mfbx9da4/instructorlist-frontend live example https://instructorlist-frontend.herokuapp.com/search/